# Issue with retrieving video statistics using youtube data api

Tags: api, youtube

I am using following youtbe data api url:

"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=ZR2GpiDE4FI&key=yourkey"

I am getting response:

```
   {
     "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
     "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/pox2n0n-cJSP1MGKUsoLm6qpH8E\"",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 1,
      "resultsPerPage": 1
     },
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#video",
       "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/iVM0LfP5vvHBM6wl1BhD0yBeR9k\"",
       "id": "eZSe4xVXHhI"
      }
     ]
    }
```

statistics node is missing from the response .

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is statistics node and why do you expect it to be there?

Comment: It is still working. Just some server issues I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per the YouTube API docs, the statistics can be part of the response: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

I have noticed this as well last week that statistics for certain videos were empty.

Looks like there has been some change in the YouTube API and they stopped returning stats for older videos. Bug? New feature? I don't know.

However I can receive the statistics for newer videos but not the old ones anymore.

Best to get some response from someone from YouTube.